# Build fortran extension on Windows with gfortran and MSVC

Tags: python

I am developing a python package using Fortran sources. I have no problem building the package using gfortran and mingw32 (`python setup.py build_ext --compiler=mingw32`) for Python 2.7, 3.3 and 3.4. However when building for Python 3.5, I get the following error (see [this build job on AppVeyor](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/cmeeren/apexpy/build/master-102/job/pe4ogcdk8wn5xmer) for details):

```
File "C:\pythontest\lib\distutils\cygwinccompiler.py", line 86, in get_msvcr
    raise ValueError("Unknown MS Compiler version %s " % msc_ver)
ValueError: Unknown MS Compiler version 1900
```

Based on [this Python issue](http://bugs.python.org/issue4709) I understand that building with `mingw32` for Python 3.5 will not be possible anytime soon. As far as I know that leaves me with the option of using the `msvc` compiler (`python setup.py build_ext --compiler=msvc`). However, still using gfortran, I get the following errors ([details here](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/cmeeren/apexpy/build/master-115/job/kyip60ls5t5lo3yq)):

```
checkapexsh.o : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _gfortran_st_write
apexsh.o : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _gfortran_st_write
magfld.o : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _gfortran_st_write
apex.o : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _gfortran_st_write
makeapexsh.o : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _gfortran_st_write
apexsh.o : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _gfortran_transfer_character_write
checkapexsh.o : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _gfortran_transfer_character_write
checkapexsh.o : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _gfortran_st_write_done
apexsh.o : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _gfortran_st_write_done
magfld.o : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _gfortran_st_write_done
apex.o : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _gfortran_st_write_done
makeapexsh.o : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _gfortran_st_write_done
apexsh.o : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _gfortran_runtime_error_at
[et cetera]
```

This is the reason I chose to use MinGW in the first place. However, I want to support Python >= 3.5 too. Is there any way I can compile fortran extension on Windows with gfortran and MSVC and avoid the errors above? Alternatively, are there other (free) fortran compilers I can use that play nice with MSVC? (I've had a hard time finding anything.)

If it's relevant, [here's a permanent link to my current setup.py](https://github.com/cmeeren/apexpy/blob/47f279b031cd4ff76a65cd60dfef7df762b8dac4/setup.py).

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible yet with any released version of CPython 3.5 from python.org or any released version of mingw-w64 gfortran. Once the mingwpy (http://mingwpy.github.io/) project progresses further this will hopefully be possible with the python.org version of CPython 3.5. This may be possible within Anaconda Python's 3.5 distribution but I'm not sure.

An alternative you can try now is installing MSYS2 from https://msys2.github.io/ then using pacman to install the mingw-w64-python3 distribution of CPython 3.5. This version of Python is itself built with MinGW-w64 GCC, so does not have the same MSVC-vs-GCC compatibility issues that the python.org build of CPython does. However if you try to download or compile binary packages that are built using MSVC, you will hit issues. The version of pip from this MSYS2 Python distribution may be configured to avoid downloading MSVC binaries, and instead default to building packages from source with the MSYS2 mingw-w64-gcc (and mingw-w64-gcc-fortran for f2py) compiler.