# installing issues relating to ffnet module Python

Tags: python

I was trying to install 'ffnet' module in Python but even after  installing Microsoft Visual Studio C++ and mingw32.

But these are the errors which are showing up:

```
1.' Failed building wheel for ffnet'
2.#Command "c:\anaconda3\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, #tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\AKSHAY~1.BAB\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-#930xyr3q\\ffnet\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)####(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record #C:\Users\AKSHAY~1.BAB\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-_pl92yit-record\install-record.txt #--single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 255 in C:\Users\AKSHAY~1.BAB\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-930xyr3q\ffnet\
```

Please anyone Help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows + Python-3.5 fortran extensions cannot be built 
anymore with f2py and mingw32 compilers, because of new MSVC used for python build. See: [Build fortran extension on Windows with gfortran and MSVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33822554/build-fortran-extension-on-windows-with-gfortran-and-msvc)

Maybe you could try python 3.4 instead?